# Magento Generates System.log as Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: magento-1.8, php, frontend, currency, log

System.log generates following Error

```
2014-06-28T12:34:58+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference  in
 D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\DOMAINNAME\app\design\frontend\THEME\default\template\directory\currency-top.phtml on line 9
```

The Code at Line 9 is as follows :

```
$last_item = end(($this->getCurrencies()));
```

I referred this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636166/only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698963/only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference), But No Success

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a PHP problem than a Magento problem. As both of your links point out, `end` is expecting an array, not a function result. A function result is not equivalent to an array even if its return type is "array".

You need to do the following to fix this issue:

```
$currencies = $this->getCurrencies();
$lastCurrency = end($currencies);
```

Assuming, of course, that the `getCurrencies()` method is returning an array.